# ¿Porque cuando verifico si en mi base de datos existe un dato el resultado siempre es no?

Tags: php, mysqli, post

Recientemente he comenzado a aprender PHP, para ponerme a prueba decidí hacer un inicio de sesión y registro, lo tengo casi terminado, pero tengo un problema al comprobar si el correo existe o no.
Luego de mirar algunos tutoriales se da la conclusión de que tengo que hacer una consulta del correo dado por el usuario a la base de datos, luego con mysqli_num_rows compruebo cuantas filas se seleccionaron.

El caso es que esto funciona perfectamente cuando el correo lo coloco directamente en una variable, sin embargo cuando coloco el valor utilizando el método post, mysqli_num_rows me devuelve siempre el valor 0.

```
<?php
include('conexionBD.php');
//ejemplo del problema
$Correo = $_POST['correo']; 
echo $Correo."<br>";

$verificar = mysqli_query($conectar,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '$Correo' ");

if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar) > 0){
    echo "el correo esta en la base de datos<br>";
}else{
    echo "el correo no está en la base de datos<br>";
}

$filas_selecionadas = mysqli_num_rows($verificar);
echo "filas selecionadas: ".$filas_selecionadas;
?>
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo el valor no debería ser cero, ya que en la base de datos ya existe este correo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿La forma de hacer la comprobación es correcta?

Al hacer var_dump a $verificar

> object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Al hacer var_dump a $_POST['correo']

> string(24) "pablotecnico@hotmail.com"

Mi archivo de conexión:

```
<?php 
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', '');
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('DATABASE', 'estudio');

$conectar = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE)or die("error al conectar con bd".mysqli_error($conexion));

?>
```

En una de las respuestas @A.Cedano me propuso este código:

```
<?php
  $Correo = !empty($_POST['correo']) ? trim($_POST['correo']) : NULL; 
  if ($Correo) { 
    include('conexionBD.php');
    if ($conectar) { 
      $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ?";
      if ( $stmt=mysqli_prepare($conectar,$sql) ){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $Correo);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $total);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        $outPut=($total>0) ? "El Correo existe" : "El Correo no existe";
      } else {
        $outPut="Error preparando la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conectar);
      }
    } else {
      $outPut="No hay conexión";
    }
  } else { 
    $outPut="Post vacío";
  }
  echo $outPut;
?>
```

Sin embargo sigo teniendo el mismo problema.

Comment: Hola jorge, puedes verificar que se esta haciendo correctamente la conexion?

Comment: @Ruben supongo que la conexión es correcta, de lo contrario hubiera un error.

Comment: es que como estas teniendo un error que no te permite proseguir con tu script, nos puedes compartir tu conexionBD.php, claro siempre ocultando los datos personales.

Comment: no alcanzo a ver `.com` en la imagen que envías de tu base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias cosas en el código:

1. Deberías escribir un código robusto que controle todos los escenarios posibles, por ejemplo, que los datos del POST están llegando, que hay conexión, que no hay errores en la consulta SQL, etc.
2. La forma más segura de saber si hay registros es mediante un `SELECT COUNT(*)`. En mysqli, num_rows depende del buffer, por lo que en algunos casos puede darte cero aunque haya filas, porque debes leer primero todos los resultados para que te de el total de filas encontradas. Además `COUNT(*)` está optimizado. Si por algún motivo necesitas no sólo saber si hay datos, sino usar esos datos, puedes optar por una consulta donde obtengas los datos en un array y verificar ese array, pero no parece ser el caso aquí.
3. Deberías también dar seguridad a tu código implementando consultas preparadas.

Te propongo este código:

```
<?php
  $Correo = !empty($_POST['correo']) ? trim($_POST['correo']) : NULL; 
  if ($Correo) { 
    include('conexionBD.php');
    if ($conectar) { 
      $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ?";
      if ( $stmt=mysqli_prepare($conectar,$sql) ){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $Correo);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $total);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        $outPut=($total>0) ? "El Correo existe" : "El Correo no existe";
      } else {
        $outPut="Error preparando la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conectar);
      }
    } else {
      $outPut="No hay conexión";
    }
  } else { 
    $outPut="Post vacío";
  }
  echo $outPut;
?>
```

Es ciertamente un programa más largo. Pero cuando escribes código, debes pensar en todos los posibles errores, y responder a ellos. Implementando este programa evitarás riesgos y sabrás siempre lo que ocurre. Es, un código robusto, no algo escrito por salir del paso. Así debería ser todo lo que escribas.